# Simulate data for quadratically related variables

Tags: r, simulation, curve-fitting

I'm looking to simulate a dataset with two variables (X,Y) where the relation between these variables is quadratic (inverted U shape) but not a perfect trend (meaning if Y is regressed onto the terms X and X^2, then R^2 is weak). Is there a precise way to do this?

I’m looking to create something like this: 1000 pairs of XY data, with Y having a normal distribution with Mn=0, SD=1 and X being as close to a normal distribution and as close to Mn=0, SD=1 as possible. Total variance explained by linear and quadratic terms should be weak (R^2 = .05) [by total variance, I mean if I regress Y onto X and X^2, the multiple R^2 = .05]. The shape of the relationship should be an inverted U, such that predicted Y values are low for low and high values of X, but high at moderate values of X.

It is easy to create this for perfect or very strong trends, but I don't know if there is a precise way to do so when there is “noise” in the data (i.e. population R^2 is weak). Thanks for any help

Comment: Your description is far from clear for simulation. Could you write something like: Generate 1000 pair of (X,Y), X follows uniform distribution between -10 to 10, and Y follows normal distribution with mean = 3+2*X +1.2*X*X and variance = 1.3.

Comment: 1000 pairs of XY, with Y having a normal distribution with Mn=0, SD=1 and X being as close to normal distribution and as close to Mn=0, SD=1 as possible. Total variance explained by linear and quadratic term weak (R^2 = .05)

Comment: Beyond that, the curvilinear effect would simply need to be an inverse U (symmetry of that effect is not incredibly important, but perfectly symmetrical is good)

Comment: Let's see if someone else can figure out your requirement. Are you aure that R^2 = 0 .05? it is very low.

Comment: Yes, R^2 of .05. That is low in many settings, though the practical utility differs by context (e.g., explaining illness)

Comment: I don't understand your requirement either. However, what @user158565 describes would be `n <- 1000; x <- runif(n, -10, 10); y <- 3 + 2 * x + 1.2 * x^2 + rnorm(n,  sd = sqrt(1.3))`. Maybe that helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: @Drew If there is a field of research where explaining a mere 5% of the variance in the response is considered sufficient, I would be very interested to know which and why. The study of diseases is certainly is not among them.

Comment: #Roland: thanks for the response. I can create quadratic trends, but simulating data with weaker and more realistic quadratic effects is the challenge. The linear term (x) and the quadratic term (x^2), when y is regressed upon them, explain 100% of the variance there.

Comment: #Frans - This is getting down a rabbit hole, but the correlation between smoking and lung cancer is something around .08, so less than 1% variance, and obviously decades of public policy has been shaped on that. Or, if you find some small strategy that correlates .01 with company sales, and if the company is large enough, that can equate to $millions in value. The magnitude of variance explained and whether that is USEFUL is very dependent on context and how complex the outcome is.

Comment: This is clearly within our scope; I have reopened.

Comment: @Drew No, it doesn't. The variance in the simulated y data explained by x depends on the noise term (i.e., the standard deviation passed to `rnorm`).

Comment: @Glen_b The question is within our scope, but not clear enough. Seems no help was given out.

Comment: @user158565 If a question is unclear, then by all means vote to close as unclear (and in general, explain what the issue is via comment). If it's on topic it should not close as off topic. It's inappropriate for us to misdirect people trying to ask questions about the nature of the problem with their post by closing under the wrong close reason when a suitable close reason is available. If certain close voters (I'm not referring to you) can't manage to identify a suitable close  reason, then perhaps the post shouldn't be closed at all.

Comment: So follow you idea.

Comment: Can you not weaken the relationship by adding random noise? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @mdewey. Yeah, I think that seems to be the clearest way to do it. I still don't know a precise solution to achieve certain total effects (i.e. specific value of R^2), but a crude solution is to use a basic quadratic formula and then add random noise. On a somewhat related note, I've recently found the R package "simstudy" to offer some nice ways to do this

Comment: Your requirements are inconsistent: if $X$ has a standard Normal distribution and $Y$ is a U-shaped function of $X$ (plus noise), then $Y$ isn't going to be anywhere near normally distributed.